# .viminfo is read-only even after chmod 744

Tags: viminfo

I'm trying to clean out erroneous entries in my command history. Though I could (in theory) use `:call histdel("expression")` it would be easier for me to just delete the entries from the `.viminfo` file. Also, for some reason I can't get `hisdel()` to work, but that's a separate problem (probably).

When I try editing the file I'm told it is read only. When I try to save I'm told I can't do that because it's read only. I tried using `sudo vim ~/path/to/home/.viminfo`, but I get the same error. I tried `chmod 744 ~/.viminfo`. I even tried `chmod 777`. In every case I'm told the file is read only. I checked the file permissions afterward to make sure vim didn't change the permissions, but they are still the same.

I was able to edit the file with `nano`, but I hate nano, so I'm guessing it isn't a file permission issue, but rather something Vim does not want the user to do...despite the file containing the words "You may edit it if you're careful!".

Comment: When you open the file, does Vim tell you why it wants to open it read-only? It might be because you have a swapfile for it, so Vim thinks there's another Vim with the file already opened... Vim tracks read-only status in the `'readonly'` setting, so you can try to `:set noro` and then write, perhaps `:w!` to force it. Does that help? See also the `'modifiable'` setting, `:set ma?` to show its status... Hopefully that helps towards fixing this!

Comment: No. I am only alerted that it is read-only upon editing or attempting to save. There is no swap file. `:w!` worked and then all subsequent `:w` in that session worked as well.

Comment: What’s the output of the command `:verbose set readonly?` ?

Comment: `readonly` is all that it says.